# File parser for csv and xls files

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns

I made program for parsing CSV and XLS files, I just want to know if there is some space to improvement and is it all written good?

My goal is when I got CSV or XLS file to parse that file and got list of objects for specific class, besides of getting list I made metod to populate datatable and show data in DataGridView.

I made two custom attribute classes for specifying column position, column name, column caption, data format (e.g. Date - "dd.MM.yyyy" and similar...) and skip from parsing.

```
public class FileHelperAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int DataPosition { get; set; }

    public string Format { get; set; }

    public bool Skip { get; set; }

    public FileHelperAttribute(int position, string format = "", bool skip = false)
    {
        this.DataPosition = position;
        this.Format = format;
        this.Skip = skip;
    }

}

public class DataColumnHelperAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }

    public string Caption { get; set; }

    public DataColumnHelperAttribute(string columnName, string caption)
    {
        this.ColumnName = columnName;
        this.Caption = caption;
    }

}
```

I defined generic interface IFileParser:

```
public interface IFileParser<out T>
{
    bool HasHeader { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<T> ReadFile(string path);

    DataTable GetDataTable(string path);

}
```

And generic class CsvParser which implements interface IFileParser:

```
public class CsvParser<T> : IFileParser<T>
{       
    public bool HasHeader { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<T> ReadFile(string path)
    {
    
        using (TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(path))
        {
    
            List<T> lstObj = new List<T>();
    
            csvParser.SetDelimiters(";");
    
            if (this.HasHeader)
                csvParser.ReadLine();
    
            while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();
    
                T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    
                foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(FileHelperAttribute), true) && p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FileHelperAttribute), true)
                                                                                                                                 .Where(a => (a as FileHelperAttribute).Skip)
                                                                                                                                 .Any()).ToList())
                {
                    var attribute = (FileHelperAttribute)prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FileHelperAttribute), true)[0];
    
                    int dataPosition = attribute.DataPosition;
                    string format = attribute.Format;
    
                    string value = fields[dataPosition];
    
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(format))
                    {
                        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                        {
                            var ci = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.LCID);
                            ci.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 2099; //default 2029
    
                            prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(DateTime.ParseExact(value, format, ci), prop.PropertyType), null);
                        }
                        else
                            prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value, prop.PropertyType), null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(decimal))
                            prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value.Replace(".", ","), prop.PropertyType), null);
                        else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
                            prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(int.Parse(value), prop.PropertyType), null);
                        else
                            prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value, prop.PropertyType), null);
                    }
    
                }
    
                lstObj.Add(obj);
    
            }
    
            return lstObj;
    
        }
    }
    
    public DataTable GetDataTable(string path)
    {
        List<T> lstObj = ReadFile(path) as List<T>;
    
        var dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
    
        foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(DataColumnHelperAttribute), true)).ToList())
        {
            var attribute = (DataColumnHelperAttribute)prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataColumnHelperAttribute), true)[0];
    
            string columnName = attribute.ColumnName;
            string caption = attribute.Caption;
    
            dataTable.Columns.Add(columnName, prop.PropertyType).Caption = caption;
        }
    
        foreach (var obj in lstObj)
        {
    
            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
    
            foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(DataColumnHelperAttribute), true)).ToList())
            {
                var attribute = (DataColumnHelperAttribute)prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataColumnHelperAttribute), true)[0];
    
                string columnName = attribute.ColumnName;
    
                dataRow[columnName] = Convert.ChangeType(prop.GetValue(obj, null), prop.PropertyType) != null ? Convert.ChangeType(prop.GetValue(obj, null), prop.PropertyType) : DBNull.Value;
    
            }
    
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    
        }
    
        dataTable.AcceptChanges();
    
        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

I didn't write XlsParser yet but I'm planning to write using spreadsheet gear library, but it will work similar as csv parser class.

I made two classes Category and User which  represents data from file.

```
public class Data
{

}

public class Category : Data
{
    [FileHelper(0)]
    [DataColumnHelper("CODE", "Code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [FileHelper(1)]
    [DataColumnHelper("NAME", "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [FileHelper(2)]
    [DataColumnHelper("ACTIVE", "Active")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [FileHelper(3)]
    [DataColumnHelper("START_DATE", "Start date")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

}

public class User : Data
{
    [FileHelper(0)]
    [DataColumnHelper("FIRST_NAME", "First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [FileHelper(1)]
    [DataColumnHelper("LAST_NAME", "Last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [FileHelper(2)]
    [DataColumnHelper("ADDRESS", "Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [FileHelper(3)]
    [DataColumnHelper("PHONE", "Phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public enum DataType
{
    Category,
    User
}

public class DataFactory
{
    public static IFileParser<Data> Create(DataType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case DataType.Category:
                return new CsvParser<Category>();
            case DataType.User:
                return new CsvParser<User>();
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException("");
        }
            
    }
}

static void PopulateDataGridView(string path)
{
 IFileParser<Data> fileParser = FileParser.Factory(DataType.User);
 DataTable dataTable = fileParser.GetDataTable(path);

 ... // pass datatable to DataGridView control...

}
```

My question now is it better to keep separately attribute classes or make one attribute class with all neded information (properties)? If I keep them separately is it better to make another class that would had method which returns DataTable?

Edit: Changed factory class.